Ultra 5 125H frequency is too low on Ubuntu 24.04
I have a laptop with an Ultra 5 125H CPU. I installed the Ubuntu 24.04 operating system, but when I checked the CPU information, I found that the maximum frequency was only 1200 MHz. However, on this laptop, the CPU frequency is indeed normal under Windows, with a base frequency of 3.6 GHz.The Linux kernel is 6.8.0-41-generic.
I used stress-ng for performance testing, but the cpu max frequency can only reach 2.0GHz, which is still a big gap from the max frequency of this cpu.
Here is the output information from my terminal：
~$ lscpu
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   18
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-17
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 5 125H
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                170
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   14
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             4
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   60%
    CPU max MHz:          1200.0000
    CPU min MHz:          400.0000
    BogoMIPS:             5990.40
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perf
                          mon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1
                          sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb intel_ppin ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow flex
                          priority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect
                          user_shstk avx_vnni dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req hfi vnmi umip pku ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq rdpid bus_lock_detect movdir
                          i movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize arch_lbr ibt flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features:
  Virtualization:         VT-x
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                    448 KiB (12 instances)
  L1i:                    768 KiB (12 instances)
  L2:                     14 MiB (7 instances)
  L3:                     18 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):           1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):      0-17
Vulnerabilities:
  Gather data sampling:   Not affected
  Itlb multihit:          Not affected
  L1tf:                   Not affected
  Mds:                    Not affected
  Meltdown:               Not affected
  Mmio stale data:        Not affected
  Reg file data sampling: Not affected
  Retbleed:               Not affected
  Spec rstack overflow:   Not affected
  Spec store bypass:      Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:             Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:             Mitigation; Enhanced / Automatic IBRS; IBPB conditional; RSB filling; PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected; BHI BHI_DIS_S
  Srbds:                  Not affected
  Tsx async abort:        Not affected

$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/cpuinfo_max_freq
1200000
700000
700000
700000
700000
700000
700000
700000
700000
1200000
1200000
1200000
1200000
1200000
1200000
1200000
700000
700000


Crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/783305/70524
